# Json return [object, Object]

Tags: php, html, json

I'm trying to display json data to html table. This is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json", function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

But I get all [object, Object], then I tried to make something like this:

```
  <table
  id="table"
  data-show-refresh="true"
  data-auto-refresh="true"
  data-pagination="true"
  data-url="https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json"
  data-side-pagination="server">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">id</th>
      <th data-field="addr" data-sortable="true">address</th>
      <th data-field="value" data-sortable="true">price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

But the last one doesn't even display anything.
What am I doing wrong?

The only error I get is that $ is not a function:

```
 $(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  })
```

This is the sample of the json:

```
{
"txs":[
{
   "lock_time":0,
   "ver":1,
   "size":192,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "sequence":4294967295,
         "witness":"",
         "prev_out":{
            "spent":true,
            "spending_outpoints":[
               {
                  "tx_index":0,
                  "n":0
               }
            ],
            "tx_index":0,
            "type":0,
            "addr":"1JR1JWDones3w2xHBLgXPYtyyBfLGcNWZY",
            "value":1205152,
            "n":0,
            "script":"76a914bf045f927639460dfca81c597c38d708ffa0173388ac"
         },
         "script":"483045022100f4385c5e87ab6bb780fbee525826e3abc7acd9f1a64f5ec89656f75fff65438502207c453930133eec554167ed4681f4310b628e80652f2d21b0b5d6577b07462d040121037aac503a15d029925f6300b7983010e1850f00d27e75ec37dddb76b65e1e0ff8"
      }
   ],
   "weight":768,
   "time":1617660671,
   "tx_index":0,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"3941a19e458794e933623af2b6b234af9f2192f4e19bd0782147fa792461a5d3",
   "vout_sz":1,
   "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
   "out":[
      {
         "spent":false,
         "tx_index":0,
         "type":0,
         "addr":"13BAFsVnZ3WeEGYEG7QFAWRyHLxLonbtcU",
         "value":1192607,
         "n":0,
         "script":"76a91417dc2355fc4309873b191274986bfaac62ffd01c88ac"
      }
   ]
},
}
```

I need to find out a way to get the value of all the addrs. This is the last I tried, but still it doesn't work:

```
    fetch('website')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const txs = res.txs;
  getElement('div').innerHTML =  'Addr: ' + JSON.stringify(txs.prev_out.addr);
```

It tells me impossible to read property of addr. Why?

Comment: The first behaviour means that `field` is not a string. We cannot know what it is, so I suggest you output it like `$("div").append(JSON.stringify(field) + " ");` Then at least you will see the object structure of `field` and can decide how to drill down to what you actually want to show.

Comment: Thank you, know it does work, I get all the json. How can I filter it know? Example, if I need to get only the addr how do I do that?

Comment: You need to show a sample of the JSON before we can answer that reliably

Comment: That depends on the structure you get. If `address` is a property of `field`, and it is a string value, then `field.address`... etc. But check a few Q&A about extracting data out of objects on this site... it is quite basic stuff.

Comment: I try but I get undefined. I'm getting the json from the link that is above in the code

Comment: You need to show a sample of the JSON here - please edit your question. Relying on external sites for info which is crucial to the question is not allowed here - these questions stay here a long time, but the content of other links can change, or the links can stop working. So please show some relevant data here and then we will help you more. Thanks.

Comment: Your right, done! See edited post

Answer (score -1):

Check one more time the response of https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions?format=json it will return an object with a property named 'txs'. There you will have all rows so you have to loop on the txs not on the response directly

Comment: How do I do that and then display it to a table? I'm trying but I not able to figure it out

Comment: I tried something like this:

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);

  var content = response.txs.inputs.addr;
  $("#div").append(content);
});

but it doesn't work. It doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't display anything

Comment: Try Someting like this:$.each( response.txs, function( index, value ) {
  console.log(value);
}); Value will be an object and you can add in table somting like this: value[0].prev_out.addr:

Comment: EDIT: I did another way, something like this:
fetch('website')
.then(res => res.json())
.then((res) => {
  const txs = res.txs;
  getElement('div').innerHTML =  'Addr: ' + JSON.stringify(txs.prev_out.addr);
But now it tells me impossible to read the property of addr. What is it wrong with it?